# PHP. How to get from MySQL result as objects and array if fields contains '{}' and '[]'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

I have some db table like this. This table contains `strings` and `numbers`, but some fields (type: text) contains `[]` arrays and  `{}` objects(json) (empty or not).

```
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| name | lastName | type | delete | rights | records | documents |
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| varch| varchar  | int  |  int   | text   | text    |   text    |
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| An   | Blabla   | 0    |  0     | []     | {"a": 1}|   {12: {}}|
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| Bn   | Blablab  | 5    |  0     |  [2,3] | {}      |   {}      |
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

DB request:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('select ' . USER_TABLE_FIELDS .' from users where
                  name = :name');
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
        $result1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and in var $result1 I have array this $key (`string`) and $value(`string` for all fields).

How can I fetch result for fileds `rights` as array, `records` as object, `documents` as object, not string?

And I know about `(object) $var` and `(array) $var`, but probably there is more simple way, becouse it can be multilevel in future.

Comment: If it's JSON in those columns(?), then your application put it there, not the database. Consequentially *you'll* have to json_decode it again. PDO has no shortcuts for that.

Comment: You should probably normalize your tables so that you have for example a table for rights and another table linking users to rights, etc.

Comment: The database model doesn't know how to construct the object or the array directly from the query because it is not a language-interpretation parser. Further, MySQL is actually language agnostic and allows you to store whatever data you want - it is up to you to parse the data on the return, however. Most often people store serialized objects in the database and unserialize them upon retrieval, but it is not a requisite.